# 3D Model to shapefile

Tags: model, 3d, gis, qgis

What workflow are available in converting 3d Model into shapefiles? I need to import a model to use as a floor plan in GIS software use.

I am able to export the model into different file format to be imported into QGIS or global mapper, but I'm unable to get the size of the model to be imported correctly into GIS. Is there anything to do with the projection or something?

Comment: Your question is generic (not much focus). What are you using now? What tools?  Why not just adding a new dimension? Usually z is very easy (you should not care about projections if you are not working on large surfaces (like continents))

Comment: I want to overlap a terrain so that I could draw road network over it in GIS software. The terrain is build as a 3D model.

Comment: This is a programmer site, so tell us about languages and libraries. If you are "just" using GIS, we have a sister site GIS.StackExchange.com (you find the link on top right icon, and then look for all sites and then search gis.

Comment: My apology and thank you.